# Mail.app smart mailbox, how to negate a search filter clause (_not_ flagged)?

Tags: mail.app

How can I negate the search criterion: "is flagged"?

I need all messages in a given mailbox, whose flag is *not* set (i.e. they are *not* flagged).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a smart mailbox containing all Flagged items, and then (this is the one you want) a smart mailbox with the 'Not In Mailbox' option to return all the items that are not Flagged, and thus not in that mailbox.

Create this first: [image: Mailbox showing all flagged items]

Then for the mailbox you want, create this one:
[image]

Worked for me in Mail 4.6, OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: But this would not validate _both_ conditions though, would it? **IN** Mailbox X **AND** _not_ flagged..

Comment: Yes, because 'not flagged' is the same as 'not in the Smart Mailbox that includes all the flagged messages'.

Comment: Actually, yours is an awesome solution and it works! Thanks!